# Deleting a node with only one child from a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree, delete-operator

This is a code to delete a node from a Binary Search Tree:
My question is: Why do we pass the node pointer **by reference** to `DelSingle` function but we only pass a node pointer to `DelDoubleByCopying` function?

```
template <class T>
bool BST<T>::DeleteNode(T& val)
{
BSTNode<T> * node = root, *prev = NULL;

if (IsEmpty() == true)
    return false;

while (node != NULL)
{
    if (node->val == val)
        break;
    prev = node;
    if (val < node->val)
        node = node->left;
    else
        node = node->right;
}

if (node == NULL)
    return false;

if (node->left == NULL || node->right == NULL)
{
    if (node == root)
        DelSingle(root);
    else if(node == prev->left)
        DelSingle(prev->left);
    else
        DelSingle(prev->right);
}
else
    DelDoubleByCopying(node);

return true;
}

template <class T>
void BST<T>::DelSingle(BSTNode<T>*& ptr)
{
BSTNode<T>* delNode = ptr;

if(delNode->left == NULL) // node does not have a left child
    ptr = delNode->right;
else if(delNode->right == NULL) // node does not have a right child
    ptr = delNode->left;
delete delNode;
}

template <class T>
void BST<T>::DelDoubleByCopying(BSTNode<T>* node)
{
BSTNode<T> *prev, *rep;

rep = node->left;  //Find the largest child in the left subtree
prev = node;
while (rep->right != NULL)
{
    prev = rep;
    rep = rep->right;
}
node->val = rep->val;
if (prev == node)
    prev->left = rep->left;
else
    prev->right = rep->left;
delete rep;
}
```

And this is the class of Binary Search Tree node:

```
template <class T>
class BSTNode
{ 
public:
BSTNode(T& val, BSTNode* left, BSTNode* right);
~BSTNode();
T GetVal();
BSTNode* GetLeft();
BSTNode* GetRight();

private:
T val;
BSTNode* left;
BSTNode* right;
int depth, height;
friend class BST<T>;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

- `DelSingle()`

Given the follwing structure

```
        parent
    ptr1    ptr2
child1
```

And sssuming we are deleting `ptr1`:

Basically, what `DelSingle()` does is to swap `child1` with `ptr1` and then get ride of `child1` (`child1` is not what `ptr1` once was).

`ptr` is passed by reference because you are **actually changing the pointer**, parent's left child is not `child1`.

- `DelDoubleByCopying()`

You don't need to pass node by reference because `node` is not going to change, the one who changes is `node->left` (or `node->right`).